# .NET windows service aborted during system shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, timeout, system-shutdown

My windows service is a data server with substantial cache. During service OnStop I save the cache so that no data is lost. Saving cache may take several minutes so to prevent windows service manager from timeout I use SetServiceStatus Win32 callback:

```
this.serviceStatus.currentState = (int)State.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
this.serviceStatus.checkPoint = 1;
this.serviceStatus.waitHint = 60000;
SetServiceStatus(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, ref this.serviceStatus);
```

That works fine.

I have also set CanShutdown to true and added OnShutdown so that service would be system shutdown proof. Here I effectively do the same thing as in OnStop:

```
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    this.OnStop(); 
    base.OnShutdown();
}
```

That does not work too good. When system shuts down, when cache is being saved I get "The device is not ready". This suggests that Windows aborts service before it is done stopping / shutting down. Preventing that with SetServiceStatus apparently does not work.

How do I get more time (delay reboot) to get saving done?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Quick question - waitHint is 60 seconds - 1 minute. Is that what you really need? (you said to need several minutes).

Comment: I just have to be the guy who raises his hand here and raises the question of why you are implementing a long-lived cache that behaves this way.  I'm not saying your whole design is invalid, I'm just saying that I smell something.  And either it could be a very fine cheese from France, or it could be something very bad.

Comment: I can see your hand raised, Dave. I know what's on your mind - have the service not keep that amount of data in memory. But that is the idea of cache. Cache is saved under several circumstances anyway but it can be loaded with data just before system shuts down. And server should rarely be rebooted at all. But I need to be prepared for worst.

Comment: @dave +1

@maciej
if your data is somehow critical you should save it immediately, there are some possible edge cases you cant cover e.g. power outage somebody pulls the plug, no more code gets executed and your data is gone no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing it looks that it was a problem with the system rather than with my service.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to handle this can be found in [this article on the BCL Team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2009/02/19/in-depth-how-net-managed-services-interact-with-the-servicecontrolmanager-scm-kim-hamilton.aspx). The article includes a bit of background on how managed services interact with the SCM, which is important for understanding why the approach shown in the question is no longer recommended.

Simply put, ServiceBase now handles service state management for you and your code just needs to request additional time if required. Read the article for a few other good guidelines for writing SCM-friendly services in .NET.

Comment: Usefull although not precise answer. I was not looking for preferred way of requesting more time from service controller (but will do it like that from now on). At the very end of that blog I found information on why shutdown differs from stop event.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) might be the trick.

Comment: I do not see how ManualResetEvent would be of any benefit here. I am not in control of thread requesting service shutdown and I do not want to synchronize with it anyway. All I want it to prevent Windows from killing my service before OnShutdown ends. Something like SetServiceStatus does for OnStop.

Comment: Since ManualResetEvent basically gives you a way to make threads wait, I thought it would help. I can see your point, though - if you can't detect when another process is going to shut down your service. Like @marc.d suggest, though, consider saving this cache more often? He has a very valid point.

Comment: It is an extreme system. I am saving cache more often but there can be too much data. It is a write cache. Data can come much faster than I can save it on-the-fly and it is a constant stream. The trick is that cache re-arranges data (from horizontally to vertically) so it is much more efficient to save it thus I need to accumulate some data before I can save it. So it is possible that when system shutdown occurs I could have no data at all or quite a lot of it.

Comment: Using ManualResetEvent would be more efficient than using Thread.Sleep

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way, after hours of searching on how to include the `setservicestatus` method:

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        stopTimer();
        m_run = false;
        while (m_queue.Count > 0)
            Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question this will work during stop but not during shutdown because service is aborted (by system) when it does not return from OnStop within within specified time.